# How I can encrypt data with 32 bits length using AES algorithm?

Tags: encryption, aes

I have a version of AES algorithm with 128bits in plaintext, now i want to change this version to 32bits in plaintext . How can i do this, please ?

---

That's part of my code when i send data to core AES, i send 128bits to encrypt and i check if the result is true.

`apb_write(x"e2bec16b",AES_CMD_ADDR_DATAIN_0);`
`apb_write(x"969f402e",AES_CMD_ADDR_DATAIN_1);`
`apb_write(x"117e3de9",AES_CMD_ADDR_DATAIN_2);`
`apb_write(x"2a179373",AES_CMD_ADDR_DATAIN_3);`

`apb_write(x"80000005",AES_CMD_ADDR_CONTROL);` --confige AES with mode (CBC)

`apb_write(x"acab4976",AES_CMD_ADDR_DATAOUT_0);`
`apb_write(x"46b21981",AES_CMD_ADDR_DATAOUT_1);`
`apb_write(x"9b8ee9ce",AES_CMD_ADDR_DATAOUT_2);`
`apb_write(x"7d19e912",AES_CMD_ADDR_DATAOUT_3);`

The question : how i can send just 32bits and check , after, send 32bits and check ....?
how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES is as far as I know only defined for blocks of 128 bits.
If you want to encrypt blocks of 32 bits, you'd need to pad your plain text (with for example 0's) until you reach 128 bits. Then, if you want to decrypt it, just decrypt it normally and after the decryption chop off the last (or first, depending which side you padded) 96 (128 - 32) bits.

Comment: yes i get you, but if I pad it up to 128 bits I think that during the encryption I will lose the information, that's mean i will get the fault result

Comment: Better to use PKCS7 padding, not zero padding.

Comment: @hamzasaber No you won't. The point is that after encryption you are able to decrypt the message into its original state. So if you encrypt `plaintext + 96 other characters`, after decryption you will be left with again: `plaintext + the same 96 other characters`

Comment: it doesn't work for me, don't forget that i'he AES 128bits in plaintext, as though I send 4 bytes by 4bytes to our core (AES) until  16bytes by the APB protocols and Now, i would like to encrypt with 4 bytes (32bits). and this technique " padding " doesn't match for me, the result is fault. what should i do ??

Comment: @hamzasaber You'll have to give some better explanation or examples, because I don't really understand your issue

Comment: @hamzasaber I don't know which environment you're working in or what you actually try to do so such specific code doesn't really help me. Anyway I'll try to rephrase what I've said before: It is simply not possible to perform AES on only 32 bits. It only works with 128 bits. That is why, whenever you want to encrypt something that is less than 32, you need to add extra characters to it (= padding). You say you want to encrypt 32 by 32, but why not just put 4 32-bit blocks together and encrypt that?

Comment: Bacause, it's part of my project an i want to compare its performance with another technique, other question please: can't we adapt this core AES with 32 bits?

Comment: AES is designed for 128 bits only. I am not too familiar with the actual procedure but maybe you can redesign it to support 32 bits. However you'd need to write most of it from scratch I suppose. If your goal is really to only encrypt 32bit blocks without padding, then AES is not for you I think.